# Possible to display/integrate numpy array with PIL?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I've asked this here twice already without getting a response. So third time lucky maybe?

How do i go about displaying a numpy array with PIL? I am trying to use the Times New Roman font with PIL and I need to display characters on a blank screen made by using a numpy array.

If i use the builtin cv2.putText function, then it works fine like so:

```
cv2.putText(blackboard, text, (4, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255))
```

output: [output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71tLe.png)

But since I have to use Times New Roman, I've used the PIL library.

Code:

```
def put_splitted_text_in_blackboard(blackboard, splitted_text):
y = 200
blackb = Image.fromarray(blackboard)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(blackb)
for text in splitted_text:
    fonts = ImageFont.truetype('Times New Roman.ttf', 50, encoding='unic')
    draw.text((4, y), text, font=fonts, fill=(255, 255, 255))
    y += 50
```

the numpy array is defined in recognize() as follows:

```
blackboard = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    splitted_text = split_sentence(text, 2)
    put_splitted_text_in_blackboard(blackboard, splitted_text)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    res = np.hstack((img, blackboard))
    cv2.imshow("Recognizing gesture", res)
    cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break


keras_predict(model, np.zeros((50, 50), dtype=np.uint8))
recognize()
```

When i run this module, the program executes fine but i don't see the text on the blank screen.

output: [Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3KH6.png)

Any help?

Comment: Can you show the result image ?

Comment: I don't see any older question from you about this. Did you use another user name?

Comment: @Sunreef I've added the output images in the original post.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Didn't get a response for 2 days so I just deleted it and posted a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a PIL image from your `blackboard` numpy array and drawing to it but you're not writing the result back to the Numpy array. Try adding `return np.array(blackb)` at the end of your `put_splitted_text_in_blackboard` function and use that in the rest of your program.

Comment: I added the line but now it seems like the `blackboard` array is returning null as i'm getting `Local Variable "blackboard" is not used`

Comment: @ShibeshDuwadi I edited my answer to correct it. Tell me if that works.

Comment: Nope, still getting a blank screen.